# Dynamically loading Views and Controllers in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I want to know what's that proper way to handle the business logic in terms of loading the appropriate views and controllers.

I have a bunch of factories to load resources, read and write user progress (to a local file) and so forth. The user will spend no more than several seconds on a given view (there are 6-7 different ones in total) and will switch to another one with dynamically loaded resources based on his progress.

My current idea is to have a service/factory that keeps track of progress, which is loaded on the index page and then every controller sends a request to it, once it's finished. Thereafter the service changes the $state and loads the appropriate data.

I'm building my first app in AngularJS and I have tried to search StackOverflow and Google, but I still can't figure out how to approach this problem.

Even pointing me to the right direction or reading material would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to read about angular DI and design pattern

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating AngularJs app first time then follow simple steps.
1. Create one **index.JSP** file where you should run your app using `ng-app` directive and add all scripts and files.
2. create one Js file `app.js`.
add all module name in app.js and run your js using .run method.
3. maintain `services, controllers and filters, directives, templates`   seperately in different folders and in different files.
And dont forget to add module name in app.js and add path in index.jsp
4. In your services files write only **sharing business logic**.
All other business logic related to particular file write it in controller.
Here your are maintaining ajax calls so dont meshup it with controllers.

**.Service**

```
.factory('angularService', function () {
  return {
    // Write business logic
  }
})
```

5. Declare `$starteProvider` and define `.states` in your controller.

**For ex.**

```
$stateProvider.state('xyz_state', function () {
   // add url,
   // templateUrl,
   // controller
})
.controller('myFirstController', function () {
   // Add your business logic
   // scope variables
});
```

6. Maintain view pages separately.
7. Maintain `Directives` and `Filters` separately.

Answer (score 0):

In angular views are by default loaded through ajax call when it is required. If you want to do the same in controller then use require.js. which will load the controller dynamically when it is required. In require.js you can also specify your other dependency library for every view & controller which will loaded through ajax when view is called.

index.html

```html
<script data-main="js/main.js"  type="text/javascript" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

main.js

```js
require.config({
    urlArgs: 'v=1.0',
});
require(
    [
      'app'
    ],
    function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['UConnect']);  //Add your module
    }
);
```

app.js

```js
'use strict';
define([],function() {
  var app = angular.module('UConnect',['ngRoute','ngAnimate','ui.materialize','yaru22.angular-timeago']);
    app.config(['$routeProvider', '$controllerProvider', '$provide',function($routeProvider, $controllerProvider, $provide) {
      // Register your component
      app.register = {
          controller: $controllerProvider.register,
          factory: $provide.factory,
          service: $provide.service
      };
      // Add resolver for load controller through require.js
      function resolveController(dependencies) {
          return {
            load: ['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {
              var defer = $q.defer();
              require(dependencies, function () {
                  defer.resolve();
                  $rootScope.$apply();
              });
              return defer.promise;
            }]
          }
      };
    $routeProvider
    .when("/Pages", {
        templateUrl : "templates/Pages.html",
        controller: 'PagesCtrl', // Add controller name.
        resolve: resolveController(['controller/PagesCtrl']) // Call resolver to load controller.
    })
    .when("/ContactUs", {
        templateUrl : "templates/ContactUs.html",
        controller: 'ContactUsCtrl',
        resolve: resolveController(['controller/ContactUsCtrl'])
    })
    ;
    $routeProvider.otherwise('/Pages');
  }]);
  angular.element(document).ready(function () {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['Uconnect']);
  });
  return app;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I usually use the [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) & store all my views there. if your on Node environment i'd suggest add [ng-html2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ng-html2js) to your build process.

as for controllers & other JS you should minify and concat all and load just that file in the beginning.